# Vue Router - params not being passed

Tags: parameters, vuejs2, router, vue-router

I cannot seem to pass the params using Programmatic navigation, the path changes but there is an empty object params.

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
  import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

  import App from './App.vue';

  const Hello = { props: ['name'], 
  template: `<h1>Hello {{$route.params}}  </h1>`,

  };
  const World = { template: `<h1>World</h1>`};

  const routes = [
    { path: '/hello', component: Hello, props: true },
    { path: '/world', component: World }
  ];

  const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
  });

  Vue.use(VueRouter);

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
  });
```

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   {{ msg }}
   <button @click="move">werwer</button>
       <router-view/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
  },
  methods : {
    move() {
    this.$router.push({ path: '/hello', params: { name: 'Paul' } })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 19):

It appears that when doing it this way you have to use named routes.

So programmatically pushing

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'hello', params: { name: 'Paul' }})
```

and in the definition

```
 const routes = [
    { name: 'hello', path: '/hello/', component: Hello, props: true },
    { path: '/world', component: World }
  ];
```

Comment: Yes! It seems that only works with push with name, no with path

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it does not support the format anymore `this.$router.push({ name: 'hello', params: { name: 'Paul' }})`  when we have our routes defined like:

```
 const routes = [
    { name: 'hello', path: '/hello/', component: Hello, props: true },
    { path: '/world', component: World }
  ];
```

Because this is an anti-pattern it drops the ambiguous params when it finds that it is not defined on the path.
So, the correct answer would define the routes as:

```
const routes = [
    { name: 'hello', path: '/hello/:name', component: Hello, props: true },
    { path: '/world', component: World }
  ];
```

For more info and how to address this issue in other ways please read the latest vue-router changelog [here](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22).